# Arrays, different size column and rows throws IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, arrays

The program I'm writing, is suppose to create an array, read its size and inputs from an .txt-file.
Print it out in a new .txt-file, with the transpose of the matrix(array) and the max-value in the array.
The content of the .txt-file is like a downward list. The first two numbers are to set the sizes of the arrays, the following numbers below are the numbers inside it.

The code works *almost* as I want it.. as of now, it can read arrays with the same length of columns and rows - as in 5x5, 8x8 etc. print out the transpose and find the max-value.

**Here's the problem**
But I need it to also be able to make arrays the size of 3x4, 4x5, 5x8 etc, and do all the things i mentioned above.
I'm greeted with the error `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` as I try to run it.

Here's how my code looks right now: [Full Code Example](https://codeshare.io/GvHcN)

```
        int column = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine()); //Reads value from txt
        int row = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine()); //Reads value from txt

        int[,] Matris = new int[row, column]; //Creates 2D array


        //For-loop for "input"
        for (int i = 0; i < column; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) 
            {

                Matris[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine()); //Saves values to array. HERE'S WHERE I GET THE ERROR.
            }

         }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :)  Please put your (relevant) code in your questions, as the site you link to may not be around for future devs looking for answers to your questions

Comment: Also, be sure to read up [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I try to save your question, add relevant part of the code to the question and remove not needed things.

Comment: @freedomn-m I don't understand you if you think something else should be added do it, I just add the place where he receives the exception.

Comment: Thank you for editing title and code. I did'nt know of any better place to share my code, without creating a wall of text.

Answer (score 1):

`row` and `column` are swapped. Make the declaration of the array like this:

```
int[,] Matris = new int[column,row];
```

or swap the indices in the loop.